# Using $loaded vs Waiting for Promise on $bindTo in AngularFire / Firebase

Tags: firebase, angularfire

I am currently using

```
syncObject.$bindTo($scope, 'data').then(function(){
    $scope.dataLoaded = true;
});
```

to check when data sync with Firebase is completed.

After reading the documentation, I see that

```
syncObject.$loaded(  
  $scope.dataLoaded = true;
);
```

does something similar.

Is there a difference between the two methods?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The promise on `$bindTo` does indeed call `$loaded` internally.  If you were using `$bindTo`, you could use the promise callback to achieve what `$loaded` does

Answer (score 1):

Your first code block does "three way binding" and the second does not.  Also per the [documentation](https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/libraries/angular/api.html#angularfire-firebaseobject-loaded), AngularFire provides a shortcut method for things passed into `$FirebaseObject.$loaded()`